# C++14 / configure error / filezilla

Tags: gcc, configure, filezilla

```
checking whether C compiler accepts -Werror=partial-availability... no
checking whether the linker accepts -Wl,-no_weak_imports... no
checking whether g++-4.8 supports C++14 features by default... no
checking whether g++-4.8 supports C++14 features with -std=gnu++14... no
checking whether g++-4.8 supports C++14 features with -std=gnu++1y... no
checking whether g++-4.8 supports C++14 features with -std=c++14... no
checking whether g++-4.8 supports C++14 features with -std=c++1y... no
configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++14 language features is required.
```

Comment: Can you please help? Sorry for the incorrect form of question, I'm still trying to figure out how to use stackoverflow.

Comment: Your version of GCC (4.8) is *much* to old.

Comment: I just download the version 5, but still when I try to check the current version, it still says 4.8, what do I do? please help.